# How do I move a symbol in an array using coordinates?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a simple program (don't have alot of experience with java right now, still learning) that moves a symbol between "locations" in an array, so the output would look something like

"go east"

```
[ ] [O] [ ]
```

to

```
[ ] [ ] [O]
```

I have a way to do it right now where I write an If statement for every single variation, so for instance

```
if (map[0][2] == 'X') {//if I am in this room
if (dir.equalsIgnoreCase("north")) {
System.out.println("You can't go that way");
} else if (dir.equalsIgnoreCase("south")) {
System.out.println("You go south");
map[0][2] = ' ';//moving from one room
map[1][2] = 'X';//to the other
```

Which means if I have more then a few rooms, the method becomes insanely long. I'm positive there's a way to make this much shorter by giving the symbol a coordinate by making two global variables, like X and Y that represent it's location in the array, and by changing those I can change it's placement, that would only be a few lines because it would only need one variation, but I can't figure out how to link the coordinates to array movement. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: failed to clarify something. Each map coordinate is set to a class called a "Room" that gives it a description and name

Comment: If you can do it manually, you can do it automatically: if it's an array of arrays then you need to either add/subtract a value from the row and/or column depending on direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two variables called `currentX` and `currentY`:

```
int currentX = 0;
int currentY = 0;
```

These will store the position of the `X`. Then you can just access the current position by doing:

```
map[currentX][currentY]
```

This means that you only have four cases (the four directions) to handle:

```
if (dir.equalsIgnoresCase("south")) {
    if (isValidCoordinate(currentX, currentY + 1)) {
        map[currentX][currentY] = ' ';
        map[currentX][currentY + 1] = 'X';
        currentY += 1;
    } else {
        // you can't go this way
    }
} else if (dir.equalsIgnoresCase("east")) { 
    if (isValidCoordinate(currentX + 1, currentY)) {
        map[currentX][currentY] = ' ';
        map[currentX][currentY] = 'X';
        currentX += 1;
    } else {
        // you can't go this way
    }
} else if ...
```

where `isValidCoordinate` is a method you have to implement, that returns true if you can go to that coordinate.

```
private boolean isValidCoordinate(int x, int y) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna try this now and see if I can get it to work. Will mark right if I can do so

Comment: So yeah, I'm having the same problem as before. when I input Map[currentx][currenty]  it has no idea what im talking about. It thinks I'm trying to make the map location a string, not inputting the variable.

Comment: @Nemenia what is this problem? You haven’t mentioned it in your question. Is there an error message?

Comment: I may not have explained well enough. Each location on the map is it's own class, a "Room", that has a description. Each map array coordinate is a "Room" so when I try to give them coordinates, it says "Incompatible type, string cannot be converted to "Room"

Comment: Hey so I got the movement to start working, but when I tried to use the boolean example you gave, it causes the program to crash with a null exception. Do you think you could elaborate on it?